# Which gives better prores bmpcc or 600d with atomus nimja 2

Tags: prores

Which gives better prores bmpcc or 600d with atomus nimja 2. Which kit to buy.

Comment: Does the 600d send an 8-bit stream down the hdmi to the Ninja which the Ninja then 'up-converts' to 10-bit proRes? If so then I'd say the BMPCC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, understand that you are probably asking the wrong question. (I'll quickly answer it for you anyway -- the BMPCC's native 10-bit ProRes support is superior.) The real question is probably *which camera will produce a better-looking result for you*. Whose ProRes implmentation doesn't really matter, and it should not factor into this purchase decision.

Some things to take into consideration:

- Lenses. Do you already have either EOS or Micro 4/3 lenses that are any good? If not, are you able to buy decent ones for either of these camera systems? A fantastic lens on either one of these cameras would produce a much better result than a crappy lens on the other.
- The BMPCC completely destroys the 600D (and every other camera in its class) in low-light performance,so if you'll be shooting outside at night a lot or something, this alone is a huge difference.
- The 600D has the 12-minute clip record limit. If you're attempting to film, say, a concert performance, not convenient.
- While the BMPCC can thankfully now format its cards, I still don't think you can delete individual clips off it. If you aren't able to dump footage frequently because of this, maybe an issue.

Those are only a few things to think about. I would say the BMPCC is a superior camera overall and would recommend it over the 600D for most things, but again, some of its quirks may not work well for whatever you're going to be using it for.

Either way, take some time to consider your specific needs, and determine which camera will produce the better overall result for you.